# Summing the values of two same-type structs

Tags: c#, struct, reflection, operator-overloading

So I have a struct like this:

```
public struct Attributes {
    public int vitality;
    public int intelligence;
    public int dexterity;
    public int agility;
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
Attributes a = new Attributes();
Attributes b = new Attributes();
```

And what I want to achieve is this:

```
Attributes c = new Attributes();
c = a + b;
```

I want this to give me the sum of these 4 variables I specified above of those two *Attributes*s.

Inside the struct, I tried to have this:

```
public static Attributes operator +(Attributes x, Attributes y) {
        PropertyInfo[] info = typeof(Attributes).GetType().GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i < info.Length; i++) {                
            info[i].SetValue(x, (int) info[i].GetValue(x) + (int) info[i].GetValue(y), null);
        }

        return x;
}
```

This apparently doesn't work, giving me an error.

Can you guys help me about this? What could I do to achieve what I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the following:

```
public static Attributes operator +(Attributes x, Attributes y) {
        return new Attributes 
        {
            vitality = x.vitality + y.vitality,
            intelligence = x.intelligence + y.intelligence,
            dexterity = x.dexterity+ y.dexterity,
            agility = x.agility + y.agility
        };
}
```

If you don't have to, there's no need to be fancy and use reflection. It's a powerful tool but don't fall into the golden hammer fallacy. Only use it where truly necessary.

EDIT: if you really do want to use Reflection, this is a working version of your code:

```
public static Attributes operator +(Attributes x, Attributes y)
{
    FieldInfo[] info = typeof(Attributes).GetFields();
    object boxedResult = new Attributes();
    foreach (FieldInfo fi in info)
    {
        fi.SetValue(boxedResult, (int)fi.GetValue(x) + (int)fi.GetValue(y));
    }

    return (Attributes)boxedResult;
}
```

I think it warrants some explanation for what changes I made:

1. I would consider it unusual if `operator+` modified one of its operands, so I made it return a new `Attributes` struct instead.
2. You called `typeof(Attributes).GetType()` which basically took the type of `Attributes` and got the type of the type, which is definitely not what you want.
3. You were checking for property info, but `Attributes` does not have properties, only fields.
4. I explicitly boxed the `Attributes` struct before setting its fields. Boxing a struct makes a copy of it, and boxing happens when you take a value type (like any `struct` for example) and cast it to `object`. What happens is your value type (which lives on the stack) is put into a neat little reference-type box and stored on the heap, since only reference types can live on the heap. Actually, a copy of it is stored on the heap. So since `SetValue` takes an `object` parameter as the "target", the struct would be boxed every time, effectively taking your changes and applying them to a copy which is then promptly thrown away. By explicitly boxing it, I make all the changes on the same copy of your struct, and then returning that after unboxing it. This step would not be necessary if `Attributes` was a reference type.

Comment: Yeah, that'd absolutely work. However, I have many more variables than that (which all of them are an integer) and it is possible to add even more in the future. So I really want to keep it with my way.

Comment: Using reflection to save yourself work of writing operators for your class seems like a bad idea. In your place I would either stick to your attributes being typed and write the operator in the way I proposed, or make your attributes into something like `Dictionary<string, int>` and sum them with LINQ.

Comment: Sure, thanks. On the other hand, I'd really like to learn a few things about reflections as well, since I am really new into C#. So, by any chance, could you help me fix my code? I think you have understood it.

Comment: I edited my answer to include working code and explanations for why it was broken. It might take you a while to wrap your head around point nr. 4, but just go throught it a few times and read up on it on the internet. I think it's a nice thought exercise about understanding what objects really are and where they live.

Comment: Oh my god. I don't know how can I thank you, look at that beautiful code and as well as the explanation. Thank you very much. Yes, I am really new into C# and I don't even know the difference between a property and a field. So my bad. Not even saying getting the type of a type... I made this a struct and that's because I am told you can set yourself a new operator on those and not on a class. Am I wrong? And this was kinda tricky since it isn't a reference type, I'd take me days to accomplish such a thing.

Comment: Operator overloading is possible on a class as well as a struct, if that's what you mean. You can go ahead and change `Attributes` to a class and see that it still works. You can also play around with removing the explicit boxing, and then changing from a struct to a class. You'll see the exact issue the boxing avoids.

Comment: Yeah, I switched it to a class and it works even better, with cleaner code. Actually, now I get it that making it a struct was a terrible idea. Thanks again.